# Mongodb abortTransaction() not working On version 5.0.8

Tags: mongodb, transactions

I have the code block below for a MongoDB transaction:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let client = await this.mongoClient();
      const transactionSession = client.startSession();

      const transactionOptions = {
        readPreference: 'primary',
        readConcern: { level: 'snapshot' },
        writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
      };
      const db = client.db("XXX");

      try {
        const transactionResults = await transactionSession.withTransaction(async () => {

          const A = await db.collection("users").updateOne({query}, {$set: {set}}, {transactionSession}).catch(console.error);
          const B = await db.collection(this.sessionCollection).updateMany({query}, {$set: {set}}}, {transactionSession}).catch(console.error);
          console.log(A, B)

          await transactionSession.abortTransaction();

        }, transactionOptions);

        if (transactionResults) {
          console.log("The reservation was successfully created.");
        } else {
          console.log("The transaction was intentionally aborted.");
          return reject({code: 5000});
        }
      } catch(e){
        console.log("The transaction was aborted due to an unexpected error: " + e);
      } finally {
        await transactionSession.endSession();
      }
});
```

This block code logs "The transaction was intentionally aborted.", but both A and B execute on database!

Comment: They are executed outside the transaction because the `session` property is still undefined, try passing `{ session: transactionSession }` instead of `{ transactionSessions }`.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara You are a hero dude! :D